# New data frame composed of unique values of different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two data frames:

```
df1 = 
a   b
1   555
2   555
4   555
4   555
5   555
6   555
7   555
8   555
15  555
1   555
```

And

```
df2 = 
a   b
2   666
2   666
3   666
4   666
5   666
2   666
3   666
9   666
```

I want to find same values of column `a` between two data frames and put them into new data frame (also with values of other columns. Here is `b`)
Desired output is:

```
df3 = 
    a   b
    2   555
    2   666
    2   666
    4   555
    4   555
    4   666
    …
```

And so on.

I have tried:

```
df3= pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['a'], how='inner')
```

but it gives me something different

Comment: What do you mean when you say "unique values"? The question isn't 100% clear to me. Do you want `df3` to contain only rows whose value in column `a` is in both `df1` _and_ `df2`, an intersection of sorts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not much different from others solution

```py
set1 = set(df1["a"].tolist())
set2 = set(df2["a"].tolist())
inter = list(set1.intersection(set2))

df3 = pd.concat([df1[df1["a"].isin(inter)],
                 df2[df2["a"].isin(inter)]],
                  ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
df3= pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
df3 = df3[df3['a'].isin(np.intersect1d(df1['a'], df2['a']))]
```

Or:

```
idx = np.intersect1d(df1['a'], df2['a'])
df3 = pd.concat([df1[df1.a.isin(idx)], df2[df2.a.isin(idx)]], ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
print (df3)
   a    b
1  2  555
2  4  555
3  4  555
4  5  555
0  2  666
1  2  666
3  4  666
4  5  666
5  2  666
```

Answer (score 1):

Roughly, this will solve your issue:

```
(pd.concat((df1[df1.a.isin(df2.a)],
            df2[df2.a.isin(df1.a)]),
           ignore_index=True)
    .sort_values('a'))

#   a    b
#0  2  555
#4  2  666
#5  2  666
#8  2  666
#1  4  555
#2  4  555
#6  4  666
#3  5  555
#7  5  666
```